# Django rest_framework does not work on rhcloud.com

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openshift

I created very simple app with django and runable on rhcloud.com but when I try to add rest_framework like as below

file **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "rest_framework"
]
```

file **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Then see that it deployed success but when enter webpage, I get **error 503 Service Unavailable**.

I really run pip install djangorestframework when remote ssh app

I using django 1.9.6, rest_framework 3.3.3

Please share for me solution if you had it before

Comment: have you installed all the rest_framework dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you updated the **setup.py** with the djangorestframework deps?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app name:
    name='YourAppName',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app version:
    version='1.0',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app description:
    description='OpenShift App',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author name (your name):
    author='Your Name',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author email (your email):
    author_email='example@example.com',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author url (your url):
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    # GETTING-STARTED: define required django version:
    install_requires=[
        'Django==1.8.4',
        'djangorestframework==3.3.2',
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/',
        'https://pypi.python.org/simple/djangorestframework/',
    ],
 )
```

Comment: I missed 
dependency_links=[
        'https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/',
        'https://pypi.python.org/simple/djangorestframework/',
    ],
thanks